# Code that creates Application in Azure AD with global administrator username and password

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I found samples of code that create Azure AD Application via Azure AD Grapgh API.

```
var application = new Application()
            {
                AvailableToOtherTenants = false,
                DisplayName = appname,
                ErrorUrl = null,
                GroupMembershipClaims = null,
                Homepage = string.Format("http://www.{0}.com", _azureDomain),
                IdentifierUris = new List<string>() { { string.Format("https://{0}/{1}",_azureDomain, appname )} },
                KeyCredentials = new List<KeyCredential>(),
                KnownClientApplications = new List<Guid>(),
                LogoutUrl = null,
                Oauth2AllowImplicitFlow = false,
                Oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching = false,
                Oauth2Permissions = new List<OAuth2Permission>();
            }          
await graphClient.Applications.AddApplicationAsync(application);
```

**But i didn't find examples of graphClient instantiation only with global admin credentials without manual creation of additional application for this purpose.**
[Here in section 9 there is explanation of how this application has to be created.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft_azure_simplified/2015/03/22/getting-started-using-azure-active-directory-aad-for-authenticating-automated-clients-c/)
Is it correct? To use global admin credentials for authentication would require creation of application?
If i am wrong and such authentication is possible can someone please add code sample of it?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to know if  the global admin credentials is required ? Or using global admin for authentication ,creating application is required?

Comment: I think the article post in your question is correct. Creating web application is required. Because the web application  needs to get resources from a web API for this scenario.

Comment: Wayne thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a "chicken and egg" scenario.

You can't access the Graph API unless the calling application is already registered.

So you need to create the application that contains your code in the AAD tenant manually, and grant it write access to the tenant.